# Resharper and Custom Live Template Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, templates, resharper, unity-container

Working with Unity, I thought it would be a good idea to create some LiveTemplates to help out with creating configuration entries. For example, I want to create some typeAlias elements in a file called "unity.config":

```
      <typeAlias
           alias="QueryService"
           type="type,QueryAssembly"/>
```

So, I created a live template:
Shortcut: typeAlias
Available "in all files"

```
<typeAlias alias="$ALIAS$" type="$TYPE$,$ASSEMBLY$"/>
```

the unity.config file is an XML file. I put the cursor in an empty spot and type "typeAlias" and then the tab key. Nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out..

The file I was testing this with was not part of a project, but was added as a solution item. I tested the above live template in an item in a project and it did in fact work!